# I have a netcore 3.1 web application with angular 8 which works fine in my local. But api doesnt seem to work when deployed to IIS on the server

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, angular8, web-deployment, asp.net-core-3.1

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayQWr.png)I have a .netcore web application and a angular 8 front end. Both the api and the front end communicate fine on my local machine.But when i deploy to IIS on my windows server, the api isnt working. i get a 404 on my api requests from the services.

> I am using the below code to set the base url for the api call

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.serviceBaseUrl = this.getServiceBaseApiUrl();//environment.serviceBaseUrl;
    }

    ngOnInit() { }

    getServiceBaseApiUrl(): string {
        if (environment.webApiEndPoint != 'dev') {
                //prod
                let paths: string[] = location.pathname.split('/').splice(1, 1);
                let basePath: string = (paths && paths[0]) || 'supplier'//Default:supplier

                this.hostName = basePath;
                this.serviceBaseUrl = this.hostName;//+ "/SupplierScreen";
                return this.serviceBaseUrl;
        }
        else {
            this.serviceBaseUrl = "https://localhost:44381";
            return this.serviceBaseUrl;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The respones server returned 404.0 so it just means the request not found.  First of all, Please ensure asp.net core web hosting bundle has been installed. Otherwise, static file handler will take over the request and just return 404 for extensionless URL.
Secondly, please ensure the URL is correct and you have already registered the handler.

```
 <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
```

Did you host the api and angular application under the same site? Because it looks like they are sharing the port.

Comment: i have installed the .netcore hosting bundle.Also i have registered a hosting bundle as above. Still it doesnt work.

Comment: I had deployed it as separate parts in the same site. Is that wrong?

Comment: Could you collect failed request tracing log?It is appreciated if you could post the detailed error message in the report. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85

Comment: thank you for the suggestions.I am now able to deploy it on the server. It was the issue with the base url in my angular code.